# What is the difference between "extends" and "include" in Jade?

Tags: include, pug

With both of these commands I can use code from another file. As I see it when we use `extends file.jade` we can use `block`, to change blocks in `file.jade`  before the compilation. But is it the only difference and am I right?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that is fundamental difference between the two. more info: [`extends`](http://jade-lang.com/reference/extends/) [`include`](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, as @laggingreflex wrote above, there are docs on these commands: [extends](http://jade-lang.com/reference/extends/) and [include](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/).

Extra points: you can use `include` for different files, not only for jade files. Also, you can use `include` multiple times on the page. This command just includes content of the different file, straight into the place. You may think of it, as if you make a big Lego project by using (including) different small pieces.

`Extends` on the contrary takes big Lego project and substitutes marked blocks with your pieces with special `block` command. It could be used once and overwrite content of the destination file (file with the `extends` command).